# (Email API-Dynamic Template) Why does HTML code in actual email look entirely different from preview mode?

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-templates

I have added a `code` block on top of my dynamic email template (code given below). It looks perfect in Preview mode, but entirely different when actual email is sent

[image: here's how it looks]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 32px;
  color: #000000;
  font-weight: 600;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://cdn.mcauto-images-production.sendgrid.net/1714a3d54002df2a/a0f350e5-2a93-4de4-9d6b-a747ccb068a0/626x240.png" style="width:100%;">
  <div class="centered">CA {{first_name}}</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

What I am trying to achieve is some text in center of an image. Is there something wrong/missing in my code? Kindly guide me on this. Thanks!

Comment: HTML Email is a proverbial biatch - most of the time it doesn't work and if it does, it doesn't in the way you intended. Best method is 1) use method by @philnash below and 2) check your email literally on *all* major email recipient clients (and in this case literally really is not ment figuratively)

Answer (score 0):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

That isn't working because [`position: absolute` does not work in many email clients](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/positioning-display/position/). This is also why it is important to test your emails in email clients after you have used preview mode.

Check out this article on [faux absolute position](https://www.goodemailcode.com/email-enhancements/faux-absolute-position) and this [article on overlays](https://sayo1337.medium.com/overlay-email-absolute-positioning-efd2f2f09ed4) they should point you in the right direction to fix this up.